# Directory Permissions / Create Mask (Samba) (Ubuntu Server OS Directorys)

Tags: server, permissions, samba, directory

I want to understand the permissions a bit more! So I have a few questions:

Does this change the directory's permission?

`sudo chmod -R 0777 Directory`

And is there a list for the "create mask" and "directory mask" codes?

Answer (score 0):

About `sudo chmod -R 0777 Directory` I have to say yes. It change permission for all subdirectories as well .